# How to find value in a CMap if the key value has space in it in C++

Tags: mfc

I have a requirement where I am storing the key, values pairs in a MFC `CMap`. While storing the values in this map one of the key values has a space in it and properly the key and value pairs are inserted into the `CMap`.

But when I am trying to find the value of a key which has space in it (two words), the value is not returned by the `CMap` lookup command. (if key does not have space then its working fine).

May I know how to query for the value if the key has space in it in `CMap`.

key here : "hello world"
value : "Test";

```
CMap<LPCTSTR,CString> testMap;

if(testMap.LookUp((LPCTSTR)key.MakeLower(), val))
{

}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about a space character in a `CMap` key. You'll have to provide a [mcve] to allow us to solve your problem. Of course, you'd known this already, had you taken the [tour]. Make sure to read [ask] in particular.

Comment: You are using a pointer (`LPCTSTR`) as the map key. If this had worked at all, then only by pure luck (e. g. when you used only string _literals_ as the key, which are typically optimized to occupy the same memory location, when the value is the same). Use `CMap<CString,CString>` so you actually compare string _values_ instead of pointers.

Comment: @zett42 I've used CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, whatever1, whatever2>

Comment: Side note: I'd drop `CMap` altogether and use `std::map`.

Comment: As @Jabberwocky said, I would also use the `std::map`. Unless you have legacy code that  you can not touch it, there is absolute no reason at this time to write new code using `CMap` and other old school MFC collection classes.